# error: near "?": syntax error using sqlite and obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

After a suggestion on here I have tried to bind the values being passed into my queries, but I keep getting the syntax error: `error: near "?":` can someone explain why please?

```
NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"banklist" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
    if(sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        {
            // prep statement
            sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
            NSString *querySQL = @"UPDATE ? SET recipe_name=? WHERE cell_id=?";
            NSLog(@"query: %@", querySQL);
            const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        // preparing a query compiles the query so it can be re-used.
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [del.dayName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [info.name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, del.tableRowNumber);

        // process result
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    {
        // prep statement
        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
        NSString *querySQL = @"UPDATE ? SET recipe_id = (SELECT key FROM recipes WHERE name = ?.recipe_name)";
        NSLog(@"query: %@", querySQL);
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        // preparing a query compiles the query so it can be re-used.
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [del.dayName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [del.dayName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

        // process result
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
}

sqlite3_close(_database);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind a value for each `?` in the query. The 2nd parameter to the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` function is the index number. These are 1-based indexes.

In you 1st query you bind a value to the 1st `?` two times. You probably need to change the `sqlite3_bind_int` call to pass `3` as the index instead of `1`.

```
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 3, del.tableRowNumber);
```

One other possible issue is your use of `sqlite3_bind_text` for the table name. This will put the table name in quotes. As suggested by Rob, you should use a string format to apply the table name but use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` for actual values you need in your query.

Answer (score 2):

You use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` for values in your SQL, but not for table names. You have to use `stringWithFormat` for the table names and `sqlite3_bind_xxx` for the values.